# Best way to sort a tree node?

Tags: c++, sorting, nodes

Say I have created some code using a `node` class:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    vector<node> children;
    string name;
};
```

and assume that the data structure has a relatively large size in memory (e.g. 50 MiB) and is unsorted.

Is there any reasonably efficient way for me to sort all the nodes (recursively) based on `name` ***other than*** simply creating a new, sorted tree in memory and then discarding the old copy?

Clarification regarding the sorting:
The vector `children` is simply to be sorted based on each element's `name`. Nothing else affects the sorting.

(i.e. this would require me to swap two objects without deep-copying them -- is this possible in C++03 and earlier? How about later?)

Comment: Of course there is. Write a function that does that. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the type you pass to `std::vector` must be complete. `node` is not a complete type until the class definition is finished. Usually with tree structures you would have  a `vector<node*> children` or make it a binary tree with each node holding a "left" and "right" `node` pointers.

Comment: @Insilico: [Huh?](https://www.ideone.com/FbBUl)

Comment: @Mehrdad: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html

Comment: @Insilico: That's interesting but I'm confused... what's wrong with this approach? The compilers don't even seem to emit warnings and they seem to work just fine... and your link seemed to say that it's possible to do this with Boost containers, so I'm confused what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It may work but it isn't standard, AFAIK. I might be wrong, but even as of C++11 the effects are undefined if you pass in an incomplete type unless the class explicitly allows it, and I don't think `std::vector`s are one of them. If this weren't an issue there wouldn't be a Boost library for it in the first place!

Comment: @Insilico: OK, I still don't understand *why* `vector` could have a problem with it, but could you pretend as though I had used Boost's vector instead? I don't think the question would be any different.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I share the same sentiment, but at the same time I try to not write code that can have undefined effects. :-)

Comment: If I read you correctly, you want each node.children to be sorted independently of all others?

Comment: @Insilico: You do not need a complete type at certain points in instantiation. Rather simply, whilst the class template as a whole is instantiated when you declare it as a member variable, the individual member functions are only instantiated when you *call* them. This means that for a class which does not require a complete type except inside it's member functions, you can leave it as incomplete until those functions are used. The main case in point is this: http://ideone.com/R5PyF

Comment: @Mehrdad, can you clarify the question. I think I can think of a number of different interpretations. *Interpretation 1:* You mentioned 'levels'. The root node is level 0, the children of the root are level 1, the grandchildren are level 2, and so on. Do you wish each level to be treated independently of the other levels, and *all* the nodes in that level to be sorted?  *Interpretation 2:* Sort the children of each node; in particular, each child will have the same parent it had before the sort. And each parent will have the same children, just in a different order. .. to be continued ..

Comment: @Mehrdad, *Interpretation 3*. Perhaps you consider all the nodes to be in a single logical list [in order tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Pre-order.2C_in-order.2C_and_post-order_traversal) and you wish to sort them all. After this sorting, nodes will not have the same parent. Even the root, and its name, might be moved.

Comment: What do you mean by "sorting node levels"?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I mean that every node's children are sorted independently -- i.e. the children should be re-ordered, but nothing hierarchical is going on.

Comment: @zvrba: Pretend like it's a bunch of directories, each one's children being sorted by name. Nothing at one node affects another node.

Comment: @Downvoters: Care to comment what you didn't like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (i.e. this would require me to swap two objects without deep-copying
>   them -- is this possible in C++03 and earlier? How about later?)

`std::swap` is a Standard function. All Standard types provide a `swap` operation as a member function. `swap` is very common and necessary for all kinds of algorithms. The Standard `std::sort` will use `swap` to swap the nodes, so you don't have to deepcopy. You merely need to implement `swap()`.

```
class node
{
    vector<node> children;
    string name;
    void swap(node& other) {
        name.swap(other.name);
        children.swap(other.children);
    }
    void sort() {
        std::sort(children.begin(), children.end(), [&](const node& lhs, const node& rhs) {
            return lhs.name < rhs.name;
        });
        std::for_each(children.begin(), children.end(), [&](node& child) {
            child.sort();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: My `swap` is never getting called through `sort`. I'm on VC++ 2008. Ideas?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Try specializing `std::swap` instead or defining your own free function `swap` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think in silico is correct (i.e. `std::vector<T>` can't be a member of `T` because `T` is incomplete), let's ignore this for now. Instead, I guess your question is about how to move the object: as is,

```
std::sort(children.begin(), children.end(),
               predicate);
```

(with a suitable predicate) would exchange the positions of two nodes by `std::swap()`ing them. This would create a deep copy and two deep copying assignments. The easy fix is to make `std::sort()` use a custom swap function which just swaps the children vectors:

```
class node {
    ...
public:
    void swap(node& other) {
        this->name.swap(other.name);
        this->children.swap(other.children);
    };

void swap(node& n0, node& n1) {
    n0.swap(n1);
}
```

In general, for value types using allocation (directly or indirectly) you probably want to implement a `swap()` function. Since it isn't needed for the correct behavior it is something often added later to get better performance.

Comment: I think you forgot to swap the `string name`?

Comment: er, yes... I forgot about it with swapping the nodes being way more expensive. correcting...

Answer (score -2):

You can recursively traverse the tree and use std::sort() on each node to reorder the nodes. See the sort() method I have added to node.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class node
{
    typedef node storage_t;
    typedef std::vector<storage_t> children_t;
    children_t children;
    std::string name;

    struct by_name_fn {
        bool operator()(node const& lhs, node const& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs.name < rhs.name;
        }

        bool operator()(node const* lhs, node const* rhs) const
        {
            return lhs->name < rhs->name;
        }
    };

    void sort()
    {
        std::sort(children.begin(), children.end(), by_name_fn());
        typedef children_t::iterator iter_t;
        for (iter_t i = children.begin(), e = children.end(); i != e; ++i) {
            (*i).sort();
        }
    }
};
```

This will, however, do lots of copy operations. So you will probably need to change the structure of node to contain by reference rather than by value its children. That is adjust the typedef of storage_t to be either node* or some shared pointer based on what suits the rest of your program. You will also need to change the line (*i).sort() to (*i)->sort().

Comment: Habits of an old man @DeadMG. The storage_t and children_t are to separate interface from implementation. You can change how the nodes are stored by touching fewer lines. The iter_t typedef is just to keep the line short. You know 80 character terminals and all. I realise some of this will be mitigated by moving to C++11 but for the moment I am still stuck with C++03.

Comment: @BowieOwens: The *entire point* of the question was how to *avoid* the "lots of copy operations" part using **this** data structure. Telling me to change the data structure *and* ignoring the constraint is kinda ignoring the question.

Comment: You didn't stipulate that the data-structure was not up for change. Adding a layer of indirection is a often a useful technique to avoid copying. I will endeavour to ignore you questions from now on if that helps.